# ajax load data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello i'm tryin to load data from server using ajax. Here is my js

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#mc-prize").click(function(){ 
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
          url: "includes/prize.php",
          type: "GET",
          datatype: "text",
          data: {"num": num},
          cache: false,
          success: function(response){
                 $("#some-block").append(response);
         }
        });
});
});
</script>
```

Here is my prize.php file

```
<?php
$host = '#';
$user = '#';
$password = '#';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $prize_email = $_POST['email'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $user);
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM prize_numbers WHERE email = '" .$prize_email. "'") or die ("Couldn't connect to database.");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   if($row['email']) {
       echo "Your num: ".$row['num'];
    } else {
       echo "No email in db";
    }

}
?>
```

But when i'm trying to get some data from db i see an error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: num is not defined"

Whats wrong?

UPD: Sorry what is correct js for my php? What i need to place in data?

Comment: num in js is not defined

Comment: first, you are sending the ajax in GET method, and trying to catch the data in POST, in the php, so decide which method you want to use

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in your php but in the js code
this code

```
data: {"num": num},
```

the variable num is not defined anywhere in the js code

try to use this code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#mc-prize").click(function(){ 
var some_email = ''; // DEFINE HERE THE EMAIL YOU WANT TO SEND
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
          url: "includes/prize.php",
          type: "POST",
          datatype: "text",
          data: {"email": some_email,"submit": 1},
          cache: false,
          success: function(response){
                 $("#some-block").append(response);
         }
        });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: year i understand. But what is correct js for my php?

Comment: I would recommend using the shorthand $.post(url, { data-in-JSON-format }, callback-function), which is way easier in most cases because you don't want all those special things to worry about

Comment: var some_email = ''; // DEFINE HERE THE EMAIL YOU WANT TO SEND

I'm sorry but email that i want to send is email from form input

I can find input.val() and send it?

Comment: Year, i get email from input using .val()

Answer (score 0):

your num in JQuery is not defined.
Data is the parameters you're transferring out and response is the result you're getting as an output.
Just replace this line of code
 `data: {"num": num},` with `data: "email="+email_var` and add implementation of variable `email_var` (for ex: `var email_var = "simplemail@mail.org"`).

UPD: Pass email so that you can check it in PHP.

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $prize_email = $_POST['email'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $user);
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM prize_numbers WHERE email = '" .$prize_email. "'") or die ("Couldn't connect to database.");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   if($row['email']) {
       echo "Your num: ".$row['num'];
    } else {
       echo "No email in db";
    }
```